# Silverlight ListBox Drag and Drop

Tags: silverlight, drag-and-drop, telerik

I'm trying to implement drag and drop functionality between two telerik list boxes. I've done it using the following code

Listbox 1 :

```
<telerik:RadListBox x:Name="name1" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
    <telerik:RadListBox.DragVisualProvider> 
        <telerik:ScreenshotDragVisualProvider />
    </telerik:RadListBox.DragVisualProvider>
    <telerik:RadListBox.DragDropBehavior>
        <telerik:ListBoxDragDropBehavior />
    </telerik:RadListBox.DragDropBehavior>
</telerik:RadListBox>
```

Listbox 2 :

```
<telerik:RadListBox x:Name="name2" AllowDrop="True">
   <telerik:RadListBox.DragDropBehavior>
       <telerik:ListBoxDragDropBehavior />
   </telerik:RadListBox.DragDropBehavior>
</telerik:RadListBox>
```

Added this Style :

```
<Style TargetType="telerik:RadListBoxItem" >
    <Setter Property="telerik:DragDropManager.AllowCapturedDrag" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

It works perfectly but i don't want the element to be removed from the source list box when it is being dragged to the other list box

Answer (score 0):

From telerik help about a treeview (same for others):

> If you want after the drag and drop operation is completed to remove
>   the item from the tree view then do not handle the PreviewDragEnded
>   for the tree view.

so, all u need is:

```
<telerik:RadTreeView x:Name="radTreeView" Margin="8,8,20,8"
    PreviewDragEnded="radTreeView_PreviewDragEnded"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataSource}, Path=LeaguesDataSource}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource League}"
    IsDragDropEnabled="True"
    IsDragTooltipEnabled="False"/>
```

code-behind:

```
private void radTreeView_PreviewDragEnded( object sender, RadTreeViewDragEndedEventArgs e )
{
   e.Handled = true;
}
```